# Generic function for two different streams

Tags: c++, generics, stream, inputstream

I have a function, `read()`, which reads data from an image using an `ifstream`. I have also overloaded the I/O operator `>>` for the image which has exactly the same definition as `read()`, except `operator >>` works on an `istream`.

```
void read (string filename);
std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & is, Image & img); //overload >> operator
//same definition for both
```

Is there any way I could implement a generic function which could be used for both `read()` and `operator>>` overloading?

Comment: You would need a const reference to the `ifstream` to extend it's lifetime, also it would need to come as the last parameter, since it will be default one. As a result the `operator>>` won't work. So, no, no way. Also, the functions don't do the same thing. `read()` doesn't return image back anywhere.

Comment: @Incomputable You are suggesting that a read operation is performable on a `const istream`, how in the world can that be possible.

Comment: @PasserBy, I forgot to mention that problem as well. But, hey, we have good old `const_cast<>()` and hoping that it won't blow up the world.

Comment: @Incomputable No you don't, overload lvalue and rvalue references

Comment: @PasserBy, Will compiler be able to disambiguate?

Answer (score 1):

As `std::ifstream` IS a `std::istream`, your read function might simply call `operator >>`, something like:

```
std::istream & operator >> (std::istream& is, Image& img);

void read (string filename, Image& img)
{
    std::ifstream is(filename);

    if (is.is_open()) {
        is >> img;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But I do not know what to pass in as `img` in the read function. This is because `filename` is actually the image file and at the point of reading, I do not have the `Image` object created. I am simply reading the contents of the file into my 2D array for manipulation. Unless I am not thinking right?

Comment: Hard to help more without knowledge about `Image` and/or `operator >>`.